# GAE App gets socket errors when communicating with BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

Our GAE python application communicates with BigQuery using the Google Api Client for Python (currently we use version **1.3.1**) with the GAE-specific authentication helpers. Very often we get a socket error while communicating with BigQuery.

More specifically, we build a python Google API client as follows

```
1. bq_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
2. credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=bq_scope)
3. http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
4. bq_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
```

We then interact with the BQ service and get the following error

> File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/gae_override/httplib.py", line 536, in getresponse
>       'An error occured while connecting to the server: %s' % e)
>   error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: [api url...]

The error raised is of type **google.appengine.api.remote_socket._remote_socket_error.error**, not an exception that wraps the error.

Initially we thought that it might be timeout-related, so we also tried setting a timeout altering line 3 in the above snippet to

```
3. http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(timeout=60))
```

However, according to the log output of client library the API call takes less than 1 second to crash and explicitly setting the timeout did not change the system behavior.

Note that the error occurs in various API calls, not just a single one, and usually this happens on very light operations, for example we often see the error while polling BQ for a job status and rarely on data fetching. When we re-run the operation, the system works.

Any idea why this might happen and -perhaps- a best-practice to handle it?

Comment: does SSL work properly? maybe try deactivating SSL verify peer.

Comment: I am seeing the same error intermittently as well.

Comment: Regarding @Pentium10's reccomdenation, we have http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True, timeout=30)) and we are still seeing some errors

Answer (score 0):

All HTTP(s) requests will be routed through the urlfetch service.

Beneath that, the Google Api Client for Python uses httplib2 to make HTTP(s) requests and under the covers this library uses socket.

Since the error is coming from socket you might try to set the timeout there.

```
import socket
timeout = 30
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
```

If we continue up the stack httplib2 will use the timeout parameter from the socket level timeout.

http://httplib2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libhttplib2.html

Moving further up the stack you can set the timeout and retries for BigQuery.

```
try:
    timeout = 30000
    num_retries = 5
    query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
    query_data = {
        'query': (query_var),
        'timeoutMs': timeout,
    }
```

And finally you can set the timeout for urlfetch.

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(30)
```

If you believe it's timeout related you might want to test each library / level to make sure the timeout is being passed correctly.  You can also use a basic timer to see the results.

```
start_query = time.time()
query_response = query_request.query(
projectId='<project_name>',
body=query_data).execute(num_retries=num_retries)
end_query = time.time()
logging.info(end_query - start_query)
```

There are dozens of questions about timeout and deadline exceeded for GAE and BigQuery on this site so I wouldn't be surprised if you're hitting something weird.

Good luck!